# Proving the Power Rule for differentiation when the power is a real number

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let, $f(x)=x^{n}$. Then,
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^{n}-x^{n}}{h}=f'(x)$$
If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can use the Newton 's binomial theorem to prove the power rule but how to prove it when $n\in\mathbb{R}$

The Rules are not to use the l'hospital's rule. I tried but found no way to proceed.

Comment: The binomial theorem can be extended to whatever exponent.

Comment: What's your definition of $x^n$ for $n \in \mathbb R$? Use the chain rule for $f(x)=\exp(n\log(x))$.